# Mail merge with mulitple fields - need to create list using commas and 'and'

Tags: excel, outlook, ms-office, mailmerge

I am trying to create an email mail merge which has a section to display results of multiple excel fields in a grammatically correct list format, but I can't work out how to put in the appropriate commas and 'and'.

For example: fields 1-4 could contain dog, cat, rabbit, mouse.

If all fields contain a value I'd want it to display on my document "dog, cat, rabbit, and mouse"

If only fields 1-3 contain values I'd want it to display " dog, cat and rabbit".

and so on...

I know I need to use an IF rule but I can't work it out.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**Formula 1:** 
You can add another field in Excel with the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,OFFSET(A1,,,,COUNTA(A1:D1)-1),"and", OFFSET(A1,,COUNTA(A1:D1)-1)),", and,"," and")
```

**Note:** Formula 1 doesn't work if there are any intermittent blank fields.

Please see the screenshot below:

[image: Formula 1]

**Formula 2:**

A **more robust formula** would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A2:F2),", "," and ",LEN(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A2:F2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A2:F2),",","")))
```

**Note:** The Formula 2 will also work even if there are empty fields in between the range.

Please see the screenshot below: 
[image: Formual 2]